# X-Editable set onblur: "submit" as a default behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, submit, x-editable, onblur

If you use X-Editable you are able to set some default options like

`$.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {type: "put"}`

or

`$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';`

Is there a convenient way to set for all my usages of the editable function - `onblur` to be `'submit'` and not `'cancel'`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.onblur = "submit";
```

This will update onblur for all the `editable` elements in the app.

Comment: It's been long since I asked the question and I currently don't use the plugin. However i'd suggest adding some sort of source